# Is there a way to (locally) bypass or disable an AttributeConverter during a Criteria API call?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, jpa-2.1

Suppose a `CreditcardNumb.class` with a constructor that checks if the credit-card number is valid.

I then create a `CreditcardNumbConverter.class` to convert credit-card numbers to Strings in the database:

```
public class CreditcardnumbConverter
      implements AttributeConverter<CreditcardNumb, String> {

    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(CreditcardNumb cn) {
        if (cn== null) return null;
        return cn.toString();
        }

    public CreditcardNumb convertToEntityAttribute(String cn) {
        if ((cn == null) || cn.trim().isEmpty()) return null;
        return new CreditcardNumb(cn);
        }
    }
```

This works ok, but now I want to use **Hibernate's Criteria API** (the new or the old API) to search for credit-card numbers that start with "123":

```
CreditcardNumb cn = new CreditcardNumb("123");

createCriteria(Wallet.class)
      .add(Restrictions.ilike("creditcard", cn, MatchMode.START))
      .list();
```

However, since "123" is not a valid credit-card number, the object instantiation fails. Also, this won't even compile, since the `ilike` method only accepts `String`s, not `CreditcardNumb`s.

**My question:**

Is there **any** way to (locally) bypass or disable the conversion, so that I can do something like:

```
createCriteria(Wallet.class)
      .disable(CreditcardnumbConverter.class))
      .add(Restrictions.ilike("creditcard", "123", MatchMode.START))
      .list();
```

Or is there any other way to search for credit-card numbers that start with "123" by using the Criteria API (not using HQL).

Comment: No way. Rethink about your validation. Personally i do not prefer validation doing inside of constructor. Compiler looks constructor firstly before doing anything. That's why you got error.

Comment: You don't like validation in constructors? Sorry, but I don't like to have my objects in illegal states. I want to have only legal credit-card numbers, and yet be able to search using the Criteria API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the credit card column in another property of `String` type:

```
@Entity
public class Wallet {

  private CreditcardNumb creditcard;

  @Column(name = ..., insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private String creditcardStr;

  ...
}
```

The key point is to map this column as being neither insertable nor     updatable, so that its value is not persisted (otherwise Hibernate would not know whether to use `creditcard` or `creditcardStr` value to update the underlying database column).

Now your query can look like this:

```
createCriteria(Wallet.class)
  .add(Restrictions.ilike("creditcardStr", "123", MatchMode.START))
  .list();
```

Comment: Wow, very creative solution. Problem is, then you have an extra field in the class, and add other undue complexities, defeating the purpose of AttributeConverters. If this is the only way I guess I will just give up using AttributeConverters, or use this answer as a provisional solution while waiting for the Hibernate team to solve this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11415

Comment: I will accept this answer if no other better idea comes up here in the next few days.

Comment: True, it comes with a trade-off. Personally, I would map it as a String without using attribute converter at all, and create `CreditcardNumb` getter and setter which do conversion. Of course, then you would have to take care to use string value as parameter in all queries.